# New Research After Level 9?

Tags: game-dev-tycoon

I have Level 10 in most of the topics, but when I leveled them up to Level 10 most of them didn't seem to unlock anything new with research, I was just wondering if there is ANYTHING based on topics that you research after they hit Level 9/10.

Comment: What topics are you talking about? I don't recall leveling up topics in this game.

Comment: I think it's just expertise with a particular topic, and you end up getting more returns because you had more experience making games for said topic.  It's been a while.